# trabajando con FECHAS en Python

Tags: python

tengo el siguiente dataframe y debo calcular por cada legajo cuantas horas por día trabajó, en conflicto se me presenta porque como se ve en el registro 3, 4 y 5 a veces se registran 2 veces la fecha de salida, con lo cual se debería poder verificar POR LEGAJO, POR CADA DIA, que existan solamente 2 registros, uno de entrada y el otro es de salida, para luego restar ambos entre si y así sacar las horas trabajadas. Me estoy rompiendo la cabeza y no se me ocurre como hacer para filtrar los que tengan mas de 2 registros en un mismo día, he intentado varias cosas pero no me funciona ninguna, además tengo la complicación para restar el registro de entrada con el de salida porque están ambos en la misma columna, ¿alguien que me ayude?. gracias desde ya.

```py
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

from datetime import datetime

from datetime import date

df=pd.read_excel(io = "RRHH.xlsx", sheet_name="Hoja1", index_col=False)

df=df.drop(columns="x")

df=df.drop(columns="x.1")

df=df.drop(columns="x.2")

df=df.drop(columns="x.3")

df["fecha y hora"]= pd.to_datetime(df["fecha y hora"])

df=df.sort_values(by=["codigo","fecha y hora"])

Legajo=df["codigo"].tolist()

Lfechas=df["fecha y hora"].tolist()

Registros=[]

Registro=[]

a=0

for i in Legajo:

#   dia=datetime.datetime.strptime(Lfechas,"%d")

#   mes=datetime.datetime.strptime(Lfechas,"%m")

#   ano=datetime.datetime.strptime(Lfechas,"%Y")

    Registros=[Legajo[a],Lfechas[a]]

    Registro.append(Registros)

    a=a+1

df1=pd.DataFrame(Registro, columns=["Legajo","Fechas"])

print(df1)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buen día, te recomiendo leer [ask] y [tour] para familiarizarte con los lineamientos del sitio. Por favor agrega el código que has intentado utilizar aunque no funcione. Una pregunta sin código por lo general termina cerrada y/o votada negativamente

Comment: Muchas gracias,  no sabía.  Lo voy a subir en un rato

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puede hacer es que todas las fechas de un mismo día vayan a una lista. Por ejemplo, usando un diccionario donde la Key es el día y el valor es una lista de fechas de ese día.

```py
{
    "2022-07-01": [fecha_del_mismo_dia1,fecha_del_mismo_dia2,fecha_del_mismo_dia3...]
    "2022-07-02": [fecha_del_mismo_dia1,fecha_del_mismo_dia2,fecha_del_mismo_dia3...]
}
```

Luego solo tienes que restar la primera fecha registrada con la última fecha registrada. Las demas fechas de ese día las ignoras, porque (y asi lo entiendo) lo que interesa son la fecha de entrada y salida.

Podrias hacer algo como esto:

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df=pd.read_excel(io = "RRHH.xlsx", sheet_name="Hoja1", index_col=False)

# Organiza las fechas en un diccionario que tiene como key el día y value una lista de fechas de ese día.
my_dict={}
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    legado= row["Legado"]
    fecha= datetime.strptime(str(row["Fechas"]), "%Y-%m-%d %X")
    indice= row["Indice"]
    
    dia= fecha.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")    
    if not my_dict.get(legado):
        my_dict[legado]={}
    if not my_dict[legado].get(dia):
        my_dict[legado][dia]=[] 
    
    my_dict[legado][dia].append(fecha)

# Iteras el diccionario de días y restas las fechas de entrada y salida.
for legado, values in my_dict.items():
    print(f"Horas trabajadas de Legado: #{legado}")
    for dia, fechas in values.items():
        horas=(fechas[-1] - fechas[0]).seconds/3600 
        print(f"{dia} - {round(horas,1)} horas")
```

salida:

```
Horas trabajadas de Legado: #5
2022-07-01 - 8.7 horas
2022-07-02 - 7.1 horas
2022-07-04 - 8.9 horas 
2022-07-05 - 8.7 horas 
2022-07-06 - 10.5 horas
2022-07-07 - 8.8 horas 
2022-07-08 - 9.8 horas 
2022-07-11 - 8.3 horas 
2022-07-12 - 9.1 horas
```

Comment: Excelentísima idea. Voy a probar, muchísimas gracias